# create html pages dynamically with proper url

Tags: javascript, php

I want to dynamically create webpages using a php script(for example : category.php) which takes on variable 'category' and do a mysql query to get data from the server and create a webpage.

category.php

```
 < ? php
    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE CATEGORY = 'CLOTHING' ";
    $result = $db_conx->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

         /*GENERATE SOME WEBPAGE*/


         }
    }

    ? >
```

So when a user clicks a link "/category/clothing " it should pick the variable value (category = 'clothing' ) from this link and dynamically generate a webpage with the address "www.example.com/category/clothing" instead of something like "www.example.com/category/?category=clothing"

What i want to avoid is a url having '?' and '='

So I want to achieve 2 things:

1. A single php file generating pages dynamically by taking values from links like  "/category/clothing"
2. Url of the new webpage should be simple and proper "www.example.com/category/clothing" (of course it should be same as the link clicked ) and not like "www.example.com/category/?category=clothing"

Can someone write a example php or js script which can achieve this or point me in the right direction(in case its very simple)

Comment: What you're looking for is mod_rewrite in .htaccess files -http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls

Comment: are you aware of mod_rewrite using htaccess?

Comment: I think mod_rewrite will do the job.  Will it also work similarly while making ajax request using a url?

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't do this by itself. You are going to need an .htaccess apache module called mod rewrite. Here is a tutorial how to make pretty urls.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049